# Does the derivation for Kirchhoff rule assume an electrostatic situation? If so, why?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current

To apply Kirchhoff rule,  we consider lumped elements with discrete potential drops and transform the equation for voltage drops across a loop:

$$ \oint \vec{E} \cdot \vec{ds} = 0 \to \sum_i V_i =0$$

However, the left side is only true for an electrostatics case, that is stationary charges, whereas here we have moving charges but Kirchhoff rule is true, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, [the integral in question is proportional to the time derivative of a magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_SI_units_convention), that is it is zero, as long as we do not have time-varying magnetic fields. Stationary currents (i.e., the currents that do not vary in time) do not produce time-varying electric and magnetic fields.

In circuit theory one also often uses *quasistatic description*, where the change in time is present, but considered to be so slow that we can neglect its effects (this is usually the case when we include inductances and capacitors in the circuit).

Comment: Ah okay I got it, so it is  approximated as the electrostatics case